# Are there contemporaneous or near-contemporaneous accounts of the embalming of Ramanuja's body?

Tags: ramanujacharya

All we know is that there is a body at Srirangam temple that is claimed to be that of Ramanuja - preserved for centuries using no known embalming techniques.  I have read that even some priests at the temple deny this.

When was the first account that said that his body was embalmed?

Do any temple-records say Ramanuja's body is embalmed there?

Comment: "I have read that even some priests at the temple deny this." Cite sources.

Comment: There is a poster here who claims direct disciplic descent from Ramanuja.  Surely he should have some information about this.

Comment: Are you saying this is mere and justifiably unwarranted speculation on your part?